# Basis in linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

$S=(v_1, \cdots v_n)$ of vectors in $\mathbb{F^n}$ is a basis iff the matrix obtained by forming a matrix (call it A) of the co-ordinate vectors of $v_i$ is invertible

My Idea: I was able to prove the reverse direction wherein we can show that $AX =0$ has trivial solutions so linearly independent and also spans the given vector space so it is a basis.

I am not sure about the forward direction that is to prove that A is invertible. I am just confused about the coordinate vector for $v_i$. That is,we assume $S$ is a basis then how can each element  (namely $v_i'$'s) in a basis have a coordinate vector? Wouldn't it just be a single column for different vector in the vector space?

Comment: Correction: "we can show that $AX=0$ has ONLY trivial solutions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The determinant of a matrix is zero iff the vectors which form it are linearly independent.

See also:

[Using the Determinant to verify Linear Independence, Span and Basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/using-the-determinant-to-verify-linear-independence-span-and-basis)

Comment: I was thinking in a way to visualize this geometrically and what I got was the following. 
Solving $Ax=0$ is the same as asking "how many vectors x are perpendicular to all the vectors (rows) in my matrix A?". If the vectors in A form a basis of the space, there can be no vector x, except the null one, which is perpendicular to every vector in A.

Comment: Ah! Great intuitive explanation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite $A$ as a row of vectors $A_1,\dots,A_n$. Then
$$
Ax = x_1 A_1 + \dots + x_n A_n
$$
Think about

$Ax=b$ always solvable means $A_i$ generate $V$

$Ax=b$ uniquely solvable (if at all) means $A_i$ independent

If these two conditions are met, you can find $n$ solutions for $Ax_i=e_i$ (put them in a matrix). This matrix will be the inverse.

If $A$ is invertible, then for every $b$ the equation $Ax=b$ has the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$. So the $A_i$ are a basis.