# If a matrix has a linearly dependent row vector is it's determinant zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this is the case for column vectors and just wanted to check if it's true for row vectors in the matrix, and if the reason for it is anything to do with $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$

Comment: Just one linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes atleast one so that not all the row vectors are linearly independent

Comment: Having just one linearly dependent is impossible. Dependency in this sense goes all ways.

Comment: I meant like in a pair so if one is a multipul of the other

Comment: Then the other is a multipul of the first too.

Comment: One linearly dependent vector is necessarily the null vector.

Comment: Well, when you transpose a matrix, its rows become its columns and vice-versa, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The following are equivalent for a square matrix $A_{n\times n}$:

1. $A$ is non-singular
2. the rows of $A$ are linearly independent
3. the columns of $A$ are linearly independent
4. $\det(A)\ne0$

There a few mores attributes, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79384)