# Determinant of two linearly independent vectors

Tags: determinant

Can someone help me explain the relationship between two linearly independent vectors and their determinant? Is it always true that the determinant of two lin. ind. vectors is 0? Is there a proof for that?

Comment: An intuitive way of seeing it is that the dimension of the range of a matrix with linearly dependent vectors is always lower than the dimension of the space we're working in. The determinant tells us how much area/volume/etc is scaled, and if we're "going down" one or more dimensions, it will always be $0$. For example, if we're in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the range of our matrix $A$ is a plane (that is, $\dim (RanA)=2$, volume will be scaled to $0$. I recommend you to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk.

Comment: See [Using the Determinant to verify Linear Independence, Span, and Basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/using-the-determinant-to-verify-linear-independence-span-and-basis)

Comment: You’ve got it backwards: the determinant is *nonzero* when the rows/columns of the matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: @amd so does that mean we cannot infer the determinant if we know they are lin ind?

Comment: That is correct.