# Checking the existence of linearly dependent vectors from a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Assume that we have a set of vectors with cardinality $n$ in a dimension $d$ vector space. I need to check if there exists any number of $d$ vectors in the set which is linearly dependent. Is there any more efficient way than checking the linear dependence of all possible $d$-tuple vectors?

Comment: If you're doing calculations explicitly, it is helpful to note that if you write the $d$ vectors as a $d \times d$ matrix, its determinant is zero if and only if the vectors are linearly dependent. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/using-the-determinant-to-verify-linear-independence-span-and-basis) for more.